# Errors reading data from 1G file on localCluster mode with apache storm

Tags: apache-storm

Hi I'm using storm with local cluster mode for developing.
I ran a simple code that contains spout and two bolts, the code example count words from log file.
code example url :
http://kaviddiss.com/2013/05/17/how-to-get-started-with-storm-framework-in-5-minutes/

the code works perfectly with small log files (7.3M), but when I try to run a big log file (100M-1000M) I'm getting exceptions.

I set a long delay till the cluster is going down.
May I miss some configuration options here?

exceptions:

```
11326 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor - Launching worker with assignment #backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor.LocalAssignment{:storm-id "HelloStorm-1-1403522378", :executors ([3 3] [                                        4 4] [2 2] [1 1])} for this supervisor 868aff95-7b63-44d1-ad55-2dd07d9c7ba2 on port 1024 with id df052251-45ec-4bc3-a486-c2bf11a8a0fa
11336 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Launching worker for HelloStorm-1-1403522378 on 868aff95-7b63-44d1-ad55-2dd07d9c7ba2:1024 with id df052251-45ec-4bc3-a486-c2bf11a8a0fa and conf                                         {"dev.zookeeper.path" "/tmp/dev-storm-zookeeper", "topology.tick.tuple.freq.secs" nil, "topology.builtin.metrics.bucket.size.secs" 60, "topology.fall.back.on.java.serialization" true, "topology.ma                                        x.error.report.per.interval" 5, "zmq.linger.millis" 0, "topology.skip.missing.kryo.registrations" true, "storm.messaging.netty.client_worker_threads" 1, "ui.childopts" "-Xmx768m", "storm.zookeeper.                                        session.timeout" 20000, "nimbus.reassign" true, "topology.trident.batch.emit.interval.millis" 50, "nimbus.monitor.freq.secs" 10, "logviewer.childopts" "-Xmx128m", "java.library.path" "/usr/local/li                                        b:/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib", "topology.executor.send.buffer.size" 1024, "storm.local.dir" "/var/tmp//77d5cd63-9539-44a4-892a-9e91553987df", "storm.messaging.netty.buffer_size" 5242880, "supervisor.w                                        orker.start.timeout.secs" 120, "topology.enable.message.timeouts" true, "nimbus.cleanup.inbox.freq.secs" 600, "nimbus.inbox.jar.expiration.secs" 3600, "drpc.worker.threads" 64, "topology.worker.sha                                        red.thread.pool.size" 4, "nimbus.host" "localhost", "storm.messaging.netty.min_wait_ms" 100, "storm.zookeeper.port" 2000, "transactional.zookeeper.port" nil, "topology.executor.receive.buffer.size"                                         1024, "transactional.zookeeper.servers" nil, "storm.zookeeper.root" "/storm", "storm.zookeeper.retry.intervalceiling.millis" 30000, "supervisor.enable" true, "storm.messaging.netty.server_worker_t                                        hreads" 1, "storm.zookeeper.servers" ["localhost"], "transactional.zookeeper.root" "/transactional", "topology.acker.executors" nil, "topology.transfer.buffer.size" 1024, "topology.worker.childopts                                        " nil, "drpc.queue.size" 128, "worker.childopts" "-Xmx768m", "supervisor.heartbeat.frequency.secs" 5, "topology.error.throttle.interval.secs" 10, "zmq.hwm" 0, "drpc.port" 3772, "supervisor.monitor.                                        frequency.secs" 3, "drpc.childopts" "-Xmx768m", "topology.receiver.buffer.size" 8, "task.heartbeat.frequency.secs" 3, "topology.tasks" nil, "storm.messaging.netty.max_retries" 30, "topology.spout.w                                        ait.strategy" "backtype.storm.spout.SleepSpoutWaitStrategy", "nimbus.thrift.max_buffer_size" 1048576, "topology.max.spout.pending" nil, "storm.zookeeper.retry.interval" 1000, "topology.sleep.spout.                                        wait.strategy.time.ms" 1, "nimbus.topology.validator" "backtype.storm.nimbus.DefaultTopologyValidator", "supervisor.slots.ports" (1024 1025 1026), "topology.debug" false, "nimbus.task.launch.secs"                                         120, "nimbus.supervisor.timeout.secs" 60, "topology.message.timeout.secs" 30, "task.refresh.poll.secs" 10, "topology.workers" 1, "supervisor.childopts" "-Xmx256m", "nimbus.thrift.port" 6627, "topol                                        ogy.stats.sample.rate" 0.05, "worker.heartbeat.frequency.secs" 1, "topology.tuple.serializer" "backtype.storm.serialization.types.ListDelegateSerializer", "topology.disruptor.wait.strategy" "com.lm                                        ax.disruptor.BlockingWaitStrategy", "nimbus.task.timeout.secs" 30, "storm.zookeeper.connection.timeout" 15000, "topology.kryo.factory" "backtype.storm.serialization.DefaultKryoFactory", "drpc.invoc                                        ations.port" 3773, "logviewer.port" 8000, "zmq.threads" 1, "storm.zookeeper.retry.times" 5, "storm.thrift.transport" "backtype.storm.security.auth.SimpleTransportPlugin", "topology.state.synchroniz                                        ation.timeout.secs" 60, "supervisor.worker.timeout.secs" 30, "nimbus.file.copy.expiration.secs" 600, "storm.messaging.transport" "backtype.storm.messaging.netty.Context", "logviewer.appender.name"                                         "A1", "storm.messaging.netty.max_wait_ms" 1000, "drpc.request.timeout.secs" 600, "storm.local.mode.zmq" false, "ui.port" 8080, "nimbus.childopts" "-Xmx1024m", "storm.cluster.mode" "local", "topolog                                        y.optimize" true, "topology.max.task.parallelism" nil}
11337 [Thread-6] INFO  com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl - Starting
11344 [Thread-6-EventThread] INFO  backtype.storm.zookeeper - Zookeeper state update: :connected:none
11358 [Thread-6] INFO  com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl - Starting
11611 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Loading executor line-reader-spout:[2 2]
11618 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Loaded executor tasks line-reader-spout:[2 2]
11632 [Thread-16-line-reader-spout] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Opening spout line-reader-spout:(2)
Start Time: 18512885554479686
11634 [Thread-16-line-reader-spout] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Opened spout line-reader-spout:(2)
11636 [Thread-16-line-reader-spout] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Activating spout line-reader-spout:(2)
11638 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Finished loading executor line-reader-spout:[2 2]
11677 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Loading executor word-counter:[3 3]
11721 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Loaded executor tasks word-counter:[3 3]
11725 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Finished loading executor word-counter:[3 3]
11733 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Loading executor word-spitter:[4 4]
11735 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Loaded executor tasks word-spitter:[4 4]
11737 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Finished loading executor word-spitter:[4 4]
11746 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Loading executor __system:[-1 -1]
11747 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Loaded executor tasks __system:[-1 -1]
11748 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Finished loading executor __system:[-1 -1]
11761 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Loading executor __acker:[1 1]
11765 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Loaded executor tasks __acker:[1 1]
11767 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Timeouts disabled for executor __acker:[1 1]
11768 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Finished loading executor __acker:[1 1]
11768 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Launching receive-thread for 868aff95-7b63-44d1-ad55-2dd07d9c7ba2:1024
11786 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Worker has topology config {"storm.id" "HelloStorm-1-1403522378", "dev.zookeeper.path" "/tmp/dev-storm-zookeeper", "topology.tick.tuple.freq.se                                        cs" nil, "topology.builtin.metrics.bucket.size.secs" 60, "topology.fall.back.on.java.serialization" true, "topology.max.error.report.per.interval" 5, "zmq.linger.millis" 0, "topology.skip.missing.k                                        ryo.registrations" true, "storm.messaging.netty.client_worker_threads" 1, "ui.childopts" "-Xmx768m", "storm.zookeeper.session.timeout" 20000, "nimbus.reassign" true, "topology.trident.batch.emit.in                                        terval.millis" 50, "nimbus.monitor.freq.secs" 10, "logviewer.childopts" "-Xmx128m", "java.library.path" "/usr/local/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib", "topology.executor.send.buffer.size" 1024, "storm.l                                        ocal.dir" "/var/tmp//77d5cd63-9539-44a4-892a-9e91553987df", "storm.messaging.netty.buffer_size" 5242880, "supervisor.worker.start.timeout.secs" 120, "topology.enable.message.timeouts" true, "inputF                                        ile" "test_log.log", "nimbus.cleanup.inbox.freq.secs" 600, "nimbus.inbox.jar.expiration.secs" 3600, "drpc.worker.threads" 64, "topology.worker.shared.thread.pool.size" 4, "nimbus.host" "localhost",                                         "storm.messaging.netty.min_wait_ms" 100, "storm.zookeeper.port" 2000, "transactional.zookeeper.port" nil, "topology.executor.receive.buffer.size" 1024, "transactional.zookeeper.servers" nil, "stor                                        m.zookeeper.root" "/storm", "storm.zookeeper.retry.intervalceiling.millis" 30000, "supervisor.enable" true, "storm.messaging.netty.server_worker_threads" 1, "storm.zookeeper.servers" ["localhost"],                                         "transactional.zookeeper.root" "/transactional", "topology.acker.executors" nil, "topology.kryo.decorators" (), "topology.name" "HelloStorm", "topology.transfer.buffer.size" 1024, "topology.worker                                        .childopts" nil, "drpc.queue.size" 128, "worker.childopts" "-Xmx768m", "supervisor.heartbeat.frequency.secs" 5, "topology.error.throttle.interval.secs" 10, "zmq.hwm" 0, "drpc.port" 3772, "superviso                                        r.monitor.frequency.secs" 3, "drpc.childopts" "-Xmx768m", "topology.receiver.buffer.size" 8, "task.heartbeat.frequency.secs" 3, "topology.tasks" nil, "storm.messaging.netty.max_retries" 30, "topolo                                        gy.spout.wait.strategy" "backtype.storm.spout.SleepSpoutWaitStrategy", "nimbus.thrift.max_buffer_size" 1048576, "topology.max.spout.pending" 1, "storm.zookeeper.retry.interval" 1000, "topology.slee                                        p.spout.wait.strategy.time.ms" 1, "nimbus.topology.validator" "backtype.storm.nimbus.DefaultTopologyValidator", "supervisor.slots.ports" (1024 1025 1026), "topology.debug" false, "nimbus.task.launc                                        h.secs" 120, "nimbus.supervisor.timeout.secs" 60, "topology.kryo.register" nil, "topology.message.timeout.secs" 30, "task.refresh.poll.secs" 10, "topology.workers" 1, "supervisor.childopts" "-Xmx25                                        6m", "nimbus.thrift.port" 6627, "topology.stats.sample.rate" 0.05, "worker.heartbeat.frequency.secs" 1, "topology.tuple.serializer" "backtype.storm.serialization.types.ListDelegateSerializer", "top                                        ology.disruptor.wait.strategy" "com.lmax.disruptor.BlockingWaitStrategy", "nimbus.task.timeout.secs" 30, "storm.zookeeper.connection.timeout" 15000, "topology.kryo.factory" "backtype.storm.serializ                                        ation.DefaultKryoFactory", "drpc.invocations.port" 3773, "logviewer.port" 8000, "zmq.threads" 1, "storm.zookeeper.retry.times" 5, "storm.thrift.transport" "backtype.storm.security.auth.SimpleTransp                                        ortPlugin", "topology.state.synchronization.timeout.secs" 60, "supervisor.worker.timeout.secs" 30, "nimbus.file.copy.expiration.secs" 600, "storm.messaging.transport" "backtype.storm.messaging.nett                                        y.Context", "logviewer.appender.name" "A1", "storm.messaging.netty.max_wait_ms" 1000, "drpc.request.timeout.secs" 600, "storm.local.mode.zmq" false, "ui.port" 8080, "nimbus.childopts" "-Xmx1024m",                                         "storm.cluster.mode" "local", "topology.optimize" true, "topology.max.task.parallelism" nil}
11786 [Thread-6] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.worker - Worker df052251-45ec-4bc3-a486-c2bf11a8a0fa for storm HelloStorm-1-1403522378 on 868aff95-7b63-44d1-ad55-2dd07d9c7ba2:1024 has finished loading
11801 [Thread-18-word-counter] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Preparing bolt word-counter:(3)
11821 [Thread-18-word-counter] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Prepared bolt word-counter:(3)
11823 [Thread-20-word-spitter] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Preparing bolt word-spitter:(4)
11825 [Thread-20-word-spitter] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Prepared bolt word-spitter:(4)
11838 [Thread-24-__acker] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Preparing bolt __acker:(1)
11840 [Thread-22-__system] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Preparing bolt __system:(-1)
11854 [Thread-24-__acker] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Prepared bolt __acker:(1)
12173 [Thread-22-__system] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.executor - Prepared bolt __system:(-1)
112055 [main-EventThread] INFO  com.netflix.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager - State change: SUSPENDED
112058 [main-EventThread] WARN  backtype.storm.cluster - Received event :disconnected::none: with disconnected Zookeeper.
112058 [Thread-6-EventThread] INFO  com.netflix.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager - State change: SUSPENDED
112058 [Thread-6-EventThread] WARN  backtype.storm.cluster - Received event :disconnected::none: with disconnected Zookeeper.
121441 [main-EventThread] INFO  com.netflix.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager - State change: SUSPENDED
121442 [main-EventThread] WARN  backtype.storm.cluster - Received event :disconnected::none: with disconnected Zookeeper.
121442 [main-EventThread] INFO  com.netflix.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager - State change: SUSPENDED
121442 [main-EventThread] WARN  backtype.storm.cluster - Received event :disconnected::none: with disconnected Zookeeper.
121443 [main-EventThread] INFO  com.netflix.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager - State change: SUSPENDED
121443 [main-EventThread] WARN  backtype.storm.cluster - Received event :disconnected::none: with disconnected Zookeeper.
121443 [ConnectionStateManager-0] WARN  com.netflix.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager - There are no ConnectionStateListeners registered.
121444 [ConnectionStateManager-0] WARN  com.netflix.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager - There are no ConnectionStateListeners registered.
134654 [main-EventThread] INFO  com.netflix.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager - State change: SUSPENDED
134655 [ConnectionStateManager-0] WARN  com.netflix.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager - There are no ConnectionStateListeners registered.
134655 [ConnectionStateManager-0] WARN  com.netflix.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager - There are no ConnectionStateListeners registered.
134656 [main-EventThread] WARN  com.netflix.curator.ConnectionState - Session expired event received
134656 [main-EventThread] WARN  backtype.storm.cluster - Received event :disconnected::none: with disconnected Zookeeper.
134656 [main-EventThread] WARN  com.netflix.curator.ConnectionState - Session expired event received
134657 [main-EventThread] INFO  com.netflix.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager - State change: LOST
134657 [ConnectionStateManager-0] WARN  com.netflix.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager - There are no ConnectionStateListeners registered.
134657 [main-EventThread] INFO  com.netflix.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager - State change: LOST
139931 [ConnectionStateManager-0] WARN  com.netflix.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager - There are no ConnectionStateListeners registered.
149745 [ConnectionStateManager-0] WARN  com.netflix.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager - There are no ConnectionStateListeners registered.
149745 [ConnectionStateManager-0] WARN  com.netflix.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager - There are no ConnectionStateListeners registered.
149746 [main-EventThread] WARN  com.netflix.curator.ConnectionState - Session expired event received
149746 [main-EventThread] INFO  com.netflix.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager - State change: LOST
149747 [main-EventThread] WARN  backtype.storm.cluster - Received event :expired::none: with disconnected Zookeeper.
149747 [main-EventThread] WARN  com.netflix.curator.ConnectionState - Session expired event received
149747 [main-EventThread] INFO  com.netflix.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager - State change: LOST
149747 [main-EventThread] WARN  backtype.storm.cluster - Received event :expired::none: with disconnected Zookeeper.
158929 [main-EventThread] WARN  backtype.storm.cluster - Received event :expired::none: with disconnected Zookeeper.
158931 [main-EventThread] WARN  backtype.storm.cluster - Received event :expired::none: with disconnected Zookeeper.
158931 [Thread-6-EventThread] WARN  com.netflix.curator.ConnectionState - Session expired event received
158931 [Thread-6-EventThread] INFO  com.netflix.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager - State change: LOST
158931 [Thread-6-EventThread] WARN  backtype.storm.cluster - Received event :expired::none: with disconnected Zookeeper.
158932 [ConnectionStateManager-0] WARN  com.netflix.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager - There are no ConnectionStateListeners registered.
158933 [ConnectionStateManager-0] WARN  com.netflix.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager - There are no ConnectionStateListeners registered.
176934 [ConnectionStateManager-0] WARN  com.netflix.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager - There are no ConnectionStateListeners registered.
357333 [CuratorFramework-5] ERROR com.netflix.curator.ConnectionState - Connection timed out
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss
        at com.netflix.curator.ConnectionState.getZooKeeper(ConnectionState.java:72) ~[curator-client-1.0.1.jar:na]
        at com.netflix.curator.CuratorZookeeperClient.getZooKeeper(CuratorZookeeperClient.java:74) [curator-client-1.0.1.jar:na]
        at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.getZooKeeper(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:353) [curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
        at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.BackgroundSyncImpl.performBackgroundOperation(BackgroundSyncImpl.java:39) [curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
        at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.OperationAndData.callPerformBackgroundOperation(OperationAndData.java:40) [curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
        at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.backgroundOperationsLoop(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:547) [curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
        at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl.access$200(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:50) [curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
        at com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl$2.call(CuratorFrameworkImpl.java:177) [curator-framework-1.0.1.jar:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) [na:1.6.0_65]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) [na:1.6.0_65]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [na:1.6.0_65]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [na:1.6.0_65]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [na:1.6.0_65]
```

[update]

```
I got new exception running 70M file:
622366 [CuratorFramework-9] ERROR com.netflix.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl - Background exception was not retry-able or retry gave up
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Comment: did you find solution for thT ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be exactly as described: you've loaded more data into memory than your JVM can support. I assume this is happening to the spout. For very large files you'll need to break up the processing by either splitting the files in advance or streaming the files in instead of trying to load the whole file into memory.